# Programmatically control Oculus Quest camera passthrough mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

I haven't seen this in their docs. Does anyone know (or have an ETA) if we can toggle on/off pass-through camera mode programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable an AR style blend of your game and passthrough [through this API](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-passthrough/). However, it is intentionally fairly limited for security of privacy (no access to the cameras view directly).